# excel error with formula if and vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(D6=D$62;VLOOKUP(C6;D$63:E$68;2;FALSE);IF(D6=G$62;VLOOKUP(C6;G$63:H$67;2;FALSE)))
```

Can some one help? I have done this formula, but when I press enter then the answer in the cell is `false` instead of the value which is supposed to look up.

Answer (score 0):

This is returning `False` because the second `IF` formula doesn't have the third parameter specified. `IF` takes three parameters, and if you neglect the third, it will just return `False`.

What this means is that `D6 is not equal to D$62` and `D6 is not equal to G$62`, so it says `False`. In other words, it doesn't even attempt either Vlookup since neither condition is true.

Comment: If u want i can send you the paper to see whats happening?

Comment: Can you input `=IF(D6=D$62;1;0)` and tell us what it says?

Comment: sure but i need the vlookup combined with the if

Comment: Yes. In any cell, please put `=D6=G$62` and tell us whether it is `True` or `False` I suspect there is a trailing space or some other white space that makes it look they are the same, when in fact they are not.